# Custom Filter of Tables in Budibase?

Tags: javascript, filter, budibase

My aim is to filter a table for 2 criteria:

- Select only id_frontend within the value of 1-50
- If there are two or more elements with the same id_frontend, only return the most recent.

While this might be an easy task, I cannot figure out how to implement it in Budibase. I assume that a nested [Data Providers](https://docs.budibase.com/docs/data-provider) inside a [Form](https://docs.budibase.com/docs/forms) and the corresponding [filters](https://docs.budibase.com/docs/searchfilter-data) / JavaScript Bindings (see image below) might be necessary.

Any idea, how to implement this task?

Thanks!

This is what I want to achieve in Budibase.
[image: My Aim: Filtering this Table]

This is the built-in Filter method of Budibase:
[image: Filtering in Budibase]